# Reactor design with calculated values

Tags: project-reactor

I'm trying to figure out how to put together a design for an application that would use Project Reactor. Let's say I have a spreadsheet like application that needs to have values updated based on other values. There are formulas defined for the values. So example:

A = 1.5B + C

I think A, B and C would all be some kind of Flux (but I'm not sure of the specific implementation I would use), because any of the values could change based on user input, or because C might be based on another formula (e.g. C = D * E). But here's the twist, if A.Jurisdiction = "MI", then the formula becomes:

A = 1.25B + 1.25C

Except of course the business reality is that there are all kinds of quirks, perhaps there are 20 different variations, not just two.

I know how to do this in an OO fashion, but I'm trying to wrap my head around how to do it using reactive streams/Reactor.

Edit: I'm trying to figure out how/if it can be completely done in a declarative fashion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you'd like to represent your cells as `Flux<Double>`, and that each update to any cell would be an `onNext` event in said flux, and propagated to dependent cells?

To tie cells together, `combineLatest` would be adapted. You could do something like this (taking your particular example):

```
public Flux<Double> cellA() {
    if (A.Jurisdiction.equals("MI")) {
        return Flux.combineLatest(cellB(), cellC(), (b, c) -> 1.25d * b + 1.25d * c);
    } else {
        return Flux.combineLatest(cellB(), cellC(), (b, c) -> 1.5d * b + c);
    }
}
```

Each time a new value comes in either source cell, A's flux will get updated, with that new value and the last seen value from the other flux as input to the `BiFunction`.

The main difficulty would be for "editable cells" (as opposed to "formula cells", here B and C) to reflect updates in user input as a `Flux<Double>`.

You can have a look at `Flux.create()` to eg. try to bridge edit events in the UI to a `Flux<Double>`.

Answer (score 0):

From my research so far, the short answer is to watch this video and apply the lessons:

[Developing Reactive applications with Reactive Streams and Java 8 by Brian Clozel, Sébastien Deleuze - Devoxx](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cj4foJzPF80)